# How does typing of 2D arrays work in C, how do I create a function that accepts the array's subtype?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I have a file (let's call it `Other.cpp` and it's `Other.h`) with the following:

```
static const int A[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
static const int B[2] = {5,6};

void static doSomething(const int C[2]) {
// Do something with C[0]
// Do something with C[1]
}
```

I'm calling this from elsewhere in the form:

```
Other::A
```

My goal here is to be able to iterate over `A` to get the items of type `const int` with a length of 2 to feed into `doSomething()`. Equally, `doSomething()` needs to be able to accept other 2-dimensional `const int`s.

I'm getting my types mixed up so badly that I need help. How does one accomplish the above? Can I get a bit of an explanation as well?

Comment: If you want `doSomething` to iterate over every element, then given that multi-dimensional arrays are contiguous, you can pass a pointer to the first element, and a length, so `void doSomething(int *ptr, size_t size)` and call with `doSomething(&A[0][0], 2 * 2);` and `doSomething(&B[0], 2);`

Comment: I'm not looking for `doSomething()` to iterate over an array, it should only ever receive an int[2] and only carry out work on C[0] and C[1]. My issue is putting together a for loop in another file that returns int[2] from A.

Comment: Well `A[0]` is an "int[2]" and so is `A[1]`. So you can call `doSomething(A[0]);` or `doSomething(A[1]);` or `doSomething(B);`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, that's stupid easy, I think made my life extra complicated from missreading a compilation error I got. Looks like my .H file is incorrect and it can't find the reference, for whatever reason I was reading that as a type error. Thank you!